# In rails, how do I run all my model tests when I run bin/rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

When I run `rspec` or `bin/rspec` it runs all the tests from my features folder.

However this does not run my model tests in my models folders, for that I have to run each one with `bin/rspec spec/models/some_model.rb`

How do I make `bin/rspec` run all tests in every folders?

Thanks.

Comment: Rspec expects that your test files end with `_spec.rb`. Rename your model tests and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jdno said, you need to rename your rspec file from `some_model.rb` to `some_model_spec.rb`.

Although I do not recommend, but RSpec has config option `--pattern` which you can change. For example, you can add `.rspec` file in your project path with this:

```
# your_project_dir/.rspec
--pattern 'spec/**/*.rb'
```

more info about `--pattern` option can be found here: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/command-line/pattern-option